# Why TypeScript functions with variable argument counts does not accept array?

Tags: typescript

I have the following functions with variable argument counts:

```
function1(...args: string[]) {
   function2(args);   -------------> does not work!
}

function2(...args: string[]) {
   ...
}
```

Why can i call these function with multiple parameters like this:

```
this.function2("a", "b", "c");
```

and those are given within an array in the function. But i cannot call these functions with this array. Is there any easy way of doing this, other than again exposing the array to individual items?

This is the given error: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `function2(...args)`

or old fashioned

```
function2.apply(null, args);
```

Comment: this puts the first array in a new array.

Comment: @akcasoy You can also use the `apply` call, but that's basically the same as using the spread operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: None of them works for me. the first one (as said before) puts the array in a second one. the second creates a new scope appearently and i cannot use my method as it is now